# HyperV integration services v3.4 for 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, virtualization

Networking is sloooow with v3.1 How to upgrade to Integration Services v3.4 in 12.10?

modinfo output in 12.10

```
filename:       /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/kernel/drivers/hv/hv_vmbus.ko
version:        3.1
license:        GPL
srcversion:     B1AA963EEFBAE322D970F14
alias:          acpi*:VMBus:*
alias:          acpi*:VMBUS:*
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.5.0-17-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

Comment: "user135144" does not know about LIS not compatible with any Ubuntu. nlee, you are not the first asking for newest LIS and we may see that no one from Ubuntu team answer to that question. One said that LIC 3.1 (integrated since Ubuntu 12.04) is full enough to work well. We know both 3.1 has poor driver performance and lack of functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

I have 75Mb-85Mb/sec transfer with this driver

ICs v3.4 can be downloaded at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34603

Also download Linux Integration Services v3 4 Read Me.pdf. There is instructions.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.